# about two differrent opinions in mathematics

Tags: philosophy

My question is: what is the name of mathematicians who ignore the proofs by contradiction and say all of the proofs should be constructive, and what is the name of opposite opinion?

Comment: The first are "constructivists", the second are "mathematicians".

Comment: The first ones are the idiots and the second the cool guys. ;-)

Comment: Useful reading is Eric Schechter's 2001 expository paper [*Constructivism is difficult*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.111.7350&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Both descriptions can include multiple perspectives. The first view could describe either constructivists or people who don't accept the law of non-contradiction; this latter group is called paraconsistent logicians. The second view could describe either classical logicians or those who are neither classical nor paraconsistent, such as the intuitionists.